# Dockerizing composer-playground with deployed (embedded) business network archive

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I found out there is `hyperledger/composer-playground` as a [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/hyperledger/composer-playground/). It's easily startable using

```
docker run --name composer-playground --publish 8080:8080 --detach hyperledger/composer-playground
```

Now I want to make a `Dockerfile` out of it that can serve an existing Business Network Definition as demo application. It should be embedded, so no real Fabric network is required. What possibilities do I have to accomplish that?

First idea: Card file structures could be copied into `/home/composer/.composer/cards` but as far as I understand, these cards could only have the `embedded` connection type, otherwise a real Fabric network is required.

Second idea: Is there some API endpoint that could be queried to create an embedded network for a `.bna` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting idea, and with the direction of Composer playground cropping up a bit recently, it would be a good one to discuss on a [Composer community call](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/wiki/NextCommunityCall)

As for how things are now, I *think* you'll have to set everything up with a real Fabric. I haven't seen a Dockerfile that does that but seems doable. The [hosted playground](https://composer-playground.mybluemix.net) does everything in local storage and pouch DB (indexedDB) so I don't think you would be able to get a demo bna in there without changes to the playground.

One thing that I had pondered in the past was making it possible to configure where the playground looks for sample networks, and that could even include the primary 'get started' network.

Might that help in this case? Could be worth opening a [Github issue](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues) to explore the use cases if that does sound useful (pull requests gratefully accepted!)

Comment: I also had the same idea thinking about possible solutions. In the train I noticed that without internet connection, the samples are not being loaded properly from Github, so I noticed they're loaded from remote at all.
If that'd be configurable, it would help very much.

I see, an embedded network is put into pouchDB "per browser" so it's pretty impossible to ship that via Docker.
Thanks James!